# Reading AVRO or JSON records in redshift

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, amazon-redshift, avro

I am serializing and deserializing my data using Avro. I save my serialized data into S3. I am trying to read the data in s3 to redshift, but unable to read it.

**Tried With Avro Format**

S3 records -

```
{"breachId":"0eb3130c-241a-461b-99ab-4910301fa012","metricName":"SIC_FAST_TRACK","regionId":"1","marketplace":"1","glProductGroup":"14","snapshotDate":"2017-09-11","breachDate":"2017-08-14","year":2017,"baseWeekNumber":29,"weekNumber":29}
```

Command at Redshift end -

```
COPY test FROM 's3://test/test.avro'
WITH credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::355548666665:role/MY_IAM_ROLE'
FORMAT AS AVRO 'auto';
```

Error at redshift - 
[

```
Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid AVRO file
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid AVRO file
  code:      8001
  context:   Cannot init avro reader from s3 file Incorrect Avro container file magic number 
  query:     1210354
  location:  avropath_request.cpp:432
  process:   query24_642 [pid=113227]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

**Tried with JSON Format**

S3 Records -

```
{"breachId":"31847d29-e542-4468-b32e-33cfb3a191b2","metricName":"SIC_FAST_TRACK","regionId":"1","marketplace":"1","glProductGroup":"14","snapshotDate":"2017-09-11","breachDate":"2017-08-14","year":2017,"baseWeekNumber":29,"weekNumber":29}
```

Copy Command at redshift -

```
COPY test FROM 's3://test/test.json'
WITH credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::355548666665:role/MY_IAM_ROLE'
FORMAT AS JSON 'auto'
```

Output at redshift -

```
1 row with partial data uploaded in the table.
```

I am unable to understand what to do. Can someone help here?

Comment: In your JSON copy command, I am assuming you meant "FORMAT AS JSON.. " ?

Comment: Yeah, I used FORMAT as JSON.

Comment: So the JSON seems to be loaded in your table. what does the data look like ?

Comment: Out of all the columns, it loaded data in two columns essentially regionId and baseWeekNumber correctly. Others, it is just empty.